# Create a batch script to find the error message from output file, if error message found it has to run a java program

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a Windows batch script to find the error message from an output file.

I have written some sample to code to create the output file and to search for the ERROR MESSAGE "ERROR".

```
@eacho on
pdm_webstat >> pdm_webstat.txt
find /c "ERROR" pdm_webstat.txt
```

The output of the `pdm_webstat` is as follows:

```
PDM_Webstat: Invoked at 08/20/2013 13:01:56

=========================================
Report from Webengine: web:wsp
=========================================
Cumulative sessions so far = 0
Most sessions at a time    = 0
Currently active sessions  = 0

=========================================
Report from Webengine: web:local
=========================================
ERROR : web engine failed to run
```

Now I am searching for the string `ERROR` in the output file as follows:

```
find /c "ERROR" pdm_webstat.txt
```

If the error message is found I have to run the some set of statements.

Can any one help me how to write a script of the above requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
find /i "ERROR" pdm_webstat.txt >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo "ERROR" found
    REM run your Java program here
)  ||  (
    echo "ERROR" not found
    REM command if "ERROR" not found
)
```

Comment: Thank you,the code is perfect, But i am looking, if error found in the text file i have to run the same sample java program.

Comment: you can replace `echo "ERROR" ...` with another program call or whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you,
I have a java project that i need to execute based on the 'ERROR message' in Outputfile.

Is it possible to return a a value to a variable and then use that varible in IF clause.

IF Error Found(
run the java project
)

Comment: @user2700968 this works like a `IF` / `ELSE` clause, please see my edit.